# how to convert this json to array. i want display data[x] for my view as table

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

{ laporan": [ { "segmen": "pu", "judul_baris": [ { "judul": "Tanggal" }, { "judul": "Penambahan Perusahaan" }, { "judul": "Penambahan TK Baru" }, { "judul": "Penambahan TK Eksisting" }, { "judul": "Pengurangan TK" }, { "judul": "Penambahan Iuran" } ], "nilai_baris": [ { "data0": "01-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0, "data3": 0, "data4": 0, "data5": 0 }, { "data0": "02-01-2020", "data1": "48", "data2": "622", "data3": "409", "data4": "55", "data5": "8350005" }, { "data0": "03-01-2020", "data1": "0", "data2": "0", "data3": "0", "data4": "0", "data5": "0" }, { "data0": "04-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0, "data3": 0, "data4": 0, "data5": 0 }, { "data0": "Total", "data1": 48, "data2": 622, "data3": 409, "data4": 55, "data5": 8350005 } ] }, { "segmen": "bpu", "judul_baris": [ { "judul": "Tanggal" }, { "judul": "Penambahan TK" }, { "judul": "Penambahan Iuran" } ], "nilai_baris": [ { "data0": "01-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0 }, { "data0": "02-01-2020", "data1": "15", "data2": "500000" }, { "data0": "03-01-2020", "data1": "0", "data2": "0" }, { "data0": "04-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0 }, { "data0": "Total", "data1": 15, "data2": 500000 } ] }, { "segmen": "jakon", "judul_baris": [ { "judul": "Tanggal" }, { "judul": "Penambahan TK" }, { "judul": "Penambahan Iuran" } ], "nilai_baris": [ { "data0": "01-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0 }, { "data0": "02-01-2020", "data1": "60", "data2": "300000" }, { "data0": "03-01-2020", "data1": "0", "data2": "0" }, { "data0": "04-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0 }, { "data0": "Total", "data1": 60, "data2": 300000 } ] }, { "segmen": "administrasi", "judul_baris": [ { "judul": "Tanggal" }, { "judul": "Pencetakan Kartu" }, { "judul": "Pencetakan Surat" }, { "judul": "Pemadanan TK" } ], "nilai_baris": [ { "data0": "01-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0, "data3": 0 }, { "data0": "02-01-2020", "data1": "0", "data2": "0", "data3": "0" }, { "data0": "03-01-2020", "data1": "25", "data2": "10", "data3": "20" }, { "data0": "04-01-2020", "data1": 0, "data2": 0, "data3": 0 }, { "data0": "Total", "data1": 25, "data2": 10, "data3": 20

how to convert this json to array. i want display data[x] for my view as table

Comment: that is not valid json

Answer (score 0):

Your json isn't valid. Btw, you can convert the json to a php array with `json_decode()`.